# R Shiny T-test returning error with reactive input

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, t-test, statistical-test

T.test function works in my Shiny app until I make one of the variables reactive then it returns Error:variable lengths differ (found for 'Group')

```
output$t_test <- reactive({
                           t_test_result <- t.test(Age ~ Group, data, var.equal = TRUE)
                           print(t_test_result$p.value) })
```

works

```
output$t_test <- reactive({
                           t_test_result <- t.test(input$Age ~ Group, data, var.equal = TRUE)
                           print(t_test_result$p.value) })
```

Returns Error:variable lengths differ (found for 'Group')

I haven't been able to find any posts with this exact issue.

Comment: Perhaps you can post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some sample data.

Comment: The one that doesn't work assumes that there is some input with an id named "Age".  The problem is that Age will likely be a single or a few values.  `t.test()` wants whatever is on the left-hand side of the tilde to be the same length as the variable on the right-hand side of the tilde.  That's the nature of the error.

Comment: Try `t.test(data[[input$Age]] ~ Group,...)`